# Rails nested attribute localization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My error message looks like this:
"Trait links trait name can't be blank"

item_template (the root of this form) has_many trait_links
Each trait_link belongs_to a trait (polymorphic)

This is my desired result:
"Trait name can't be blank"

Three things I've tried:

1.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      item_template/trait_links:
        trait: "trait"
```

2.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      item_template:
        trait_links: ""
```

3.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      item_template/trait_links: ""
```

These don't work. How can I do this?

Thanks

Edit: The error is intentional. I want to change its text.

Answer (score 0):

The error message does not look to me like an error message related to localization. A localization error message typically says something like "missing translation en.activerecord.attributes.etc".

The error message you're seeing looks like a validation error message. You need to look at the parameters that are received by the controller to see why trait_name is blank. I'm betting that you have a line in the TraitLinks model like:

```
validate :trait_name, presence: true
```

if so, then this is the source of the error message.

The I18n key for this message would be:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        trait_links:
          attributes:
            trait_name:
              blank: "you really should enter a trait name, dude"
```

See [Rails guides on internationalization, para 4.5.1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

Comment: The error is intentional. I want to change its text.